# Implementing a circuit that takes a 3-bit number and multiplies it by 8 using only 1 4-bit adder

Tags: digital-logic

I was solving a past exam and this question popped up and nobody seemed to agree on an answer.
[image: this question]
Someone suggested this solution which is just hacking your way to the required result.

That suggested solution: 
[image: suggested solution]

My suggested solution:
I thought of a 3-bit counter that re-uses the same 4-bit adder 8 times to add the number to itself 8 times. (since 8X = X + X + X + X + X + X + X + X)
It should add the bit to its corresponding sum 8 times but I am having some issues formulating it, especially that I know the output is going to be X2X1X0000 assuming input is X2X1X0 and I don't really understand how I am going this counter-adder thing do this job.

I did some Googling and I ran into the "shift and add" algorithm but that was never explained to us in any course, not as an algorithm nor as a circuit so I figured it wasn't the solution the examiner was looking for.

Comment: I don't know what the examiner was thinking, because if all you're ever going to do is multiply by eight, you just map (in)0 to (out)3, (in)1 to (out)4, (in)2 to (out)5, collect your fee, and move on to something interesting.

Comment: Agree the *"using only 1 4-bit adder"* is superfluous and I can only think it is there to try to confuse the student.

Comment: Well, how could it be answered still? If they re-use the question I honestly can't write down that the question is full of sh** (as much as I'd love it if I could)

Comment: You could do what you want, but your 4-bit adder can't produce a 6-bit result. So you're going to have to use your *a priori* knowledge that the low bits are all 0's even to do the shift-and-add method.

Comment: Just draw a diagram passing 0 line inputs to the lowest 3 bits of your output. Then pass the inputs directly to the next 4 output bits. No adder necessary. You could get really cheeky and draw the adder connected to nothing, lol.

Comment: Consider using registers, and carry-in, carry-out pins, to implement that 6-bit adder.